# Replacing &nbsp; from HTML not working

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to remove extra space of an html element text but it doesn't work.
The original html element is:

```
<td class="thinborder" >&nbsp;text</td>
```

If i'll access this one using element.text() by Jsoup it returns:

```
" text"
```

Here are the methods that I used and all of them doesn't work:

```
String fixed = element.text().replace(" ", "");
String fixed = element.text().replace("nbsp;", "");
String fixed = element.text().replaceFirst(" ", "");
```

EDIT:
*trimming doesn't work also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)  the string

```
String fixed = element.text().trim();
```

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

And also try the regex

```
String result =  element.text().replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

And if you still not able to get it work then try to replace the unicode space

```
String result =  element.text().replace("\u00A0","");
```

Comment: @DanielGomez Can you try the regex given ?

Comment: im getting the same length for the trim(), "\\s+" seems to work ill try it with replace()

Comment: how come using replace("\\s+",""); wont work? but when I use replaceAll() it does remove all the spaces including the first one?

Comment: @DanielGomez Because replaceAll takes a regex as a first argument where as replace takes String as a first arg :) look at docs once.